# how to set up two codeigniter applications running on same server

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I build a codeigniter app a few months ago - it's a networking tool. 
Now my client wants me to build a reporting application for them - accesses the same database the networking tool does, but it's not really related.

I've downloaded a fresh / newer copy of codeigniter into a new folder under www ... but now I'm wondering this is the right way to architect the solution .. physically. 
Has anyone else tried building multiple ci applications on the same server?  Should I be / Can I combine disparate apps so that they use the same copy of the ci code? 
I've read somewhere about HMVC.  Does that apply here?  I'm going to google now as well to read up on it, but if you can just point me in the right direction, that'd be great.
Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do either.

See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/managing_apps.html for details on using the same CI install to run multiple sites.

Alternatively, you could create another CI install in another folder and point your server software or users at it.

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have two application on same server using same session names and if you login it logins another application also to avoide this issue you just need to go to config.php file under application folder and provide the unique name to cookies session

```
    For Application a

    $config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'applicationa';
    $config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
    $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
    $config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
    $config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
    $config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
    $config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
    $config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
    $config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;


    For Application b
    $config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'applicationb';
    $config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
    $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
    $config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
    $config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
    $config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
    $config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
    $config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
    $config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```